# Add data for Annotated time line of Google Chart with time

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How to add data for Annotated timeline of Google Chart with time? such as:

> [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), Time(12.2.30), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],

There is no demo on [official site](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline), is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Date object support specifying hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

so if you want to specify a time of day in the date, you just need to add the appropriate parameters.  In your example, it would be:

```
new Date(2008, 1, 1, 12, 2, 30) // 12:02:30 February 1, 2008
```